# Can I have Django template tags inside a django-compressor tag?

Tags: django, django-compressor

For example:

```
{% compress css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/foo.css' %}">
    {% if foobar %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bar.css' %}">
    {% endif %}
{% endcompress %}
```

As above, can I have an `if` tag inside the `compress` tag? Does this work with the `OFFLINE_COMPRESSION` mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it myself. **The answer is no, as of Aug. 2018.**

A workaround maybe using multiple `compress` tags as mentioned by in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

`django-compressor` docs says nothing about it. But you can use few `{% compress %}` tags like this:

```
{% compress css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/foo.css' %}">
{% endcompress %}
{% if foobar %}
    {% compress css %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bar.css' %}">
    {% endcompress %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. Thanks for the answer.